# Laravel: Is it possible to apply different form validation rules to objects in an array

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-formrequest

I have a Laravel 9 API.

I am posting the following json to an endpoint.

```
{
  "shapes": [
    {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [1, 2]
    },
    {
      "type": "MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          [
            [1, 2],
            [3, 4],
            [5, 6],
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have some form validation (in a form request class) that needs to validate the coordinates given differently based on the type.

I.e. Apply the `PointCoordinatesValidator` rule if the shape's type is Point or apply the `MultiPolygonCoordinatesValidator` rule if the shape's type is MultiPolygon.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'shapes' => 'required|array|min:1',
        'shapes.*.type' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            'in:Point,MultiPolygon',
        ],
        'shapes.*.coordinates' => [
            'required',
            request()->input('shapes.*.type') == 'Point' ?
                new PointCoordinatesValidator :
                new MultiPolygonCoordinatesValidator,
        ],
    ];
}
```

However, when running this, the custom `MultiPolygonCoordinatesValidator` rule is being applied to both shapes, not just the shape where it's type == MultiPolygon.

I can see that
`request()->input('shapes.*.type')` is Point for `shapes.0` and MultiPolygon for `shapes.1`

Am I expecting too much from the validation? Is it possible to validate the different items in the array differently based on a value in that array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the array element in and then implement the type check in your rule:

```
'shapes.*' => [
               'required',
                new CoordinatesValidator(),
              ],
```

Then, in the rule, the `$value` will contain the type and the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely *is* possible, but not by checking `request()->input('shapes.*.type') == 'Point'`; that `*` is a wildcard, and isn't really checked on each iteration.

You can construct the rules from the input, but it's a bit of an anti-pattern, and might have issues if `type` is `null`, or similar.

Give this a shot:

```
public function rules() {
  $rules = [
    'shapes' => 'required|array|min:1',
    'shapes.*.type' => [
      'required',
      'string',
      'in:Point,MultiPolygon',
    ]
  ];

  foreach(request()->input('shapes', []) as $index => $shape) {
    $rules["shapes.{$index}.coordinates"] = [
      'required',
      $shape['type'] == 'Point' ? new PointCoordinatesValidator() : new MultiPolygonCoordinatesValidator()
    ];
  }

  return $rules;
}
```

Using that, you'll get something like this:

```
[
  'shapes' => 'required|array|min:1',
  'shapes.*.type' => [
    'required',
    'string',
    'in:Point,MultiPolygon'
  ],
  'shapes.0.coordinates' => [
    'required',
    new PointCoordinatesValidator()
  ],
  'shapes.1.coordinates' => [
    'required',
    new MultiPolygonCoordinatesValidator()
  ]
  // And so on...
]
```

Your `$rules` array can get pretty large, depending on the number of `shapes` being uploaded, but this should allow you to explicitly target certain validation rules for each shape, depending on the `type` supplied.